# Tool to refactor .xsd schema?

Tags: xsd

I got an .xsd scheme that has **multiple** root elements, few complex and simple types, complex types refer to those root elements. I can't generate .xml in a way i want from it because of those root elements. So i think i need to add element that will serve as the root element, and add all other elements as its children, or am i wrong?

Is there a tool that can help me create root element and refactor scheme? What i got:
[image]

I was thinking maybe i just need to create another xsd with 1 element and ref all elements form first xsd in it, but i don't exactly know how to do it. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your edit is indeed, as Pangea said, NO. And that is because to ref another element (as in <xsd:element ref="SomeElement" ... />), the referenced element must be declared globally.

Other scenario that requires global elements is the use of substitution groups. What I am trying to suggest is that it may not always be possible to refactor an XSD in a way that leaves global only the elements you want as root in instance XML.

Which should make you think that to solve your problem, a better way might be to go after the reason why you can't generate .xml the way you want. If you can describe a bit of that, you might get a better answer here...

Another reason I wanted to add this answer was that I noticed the use of XML as a tag name. While it may seem OK, I can tell you that I've seen some pretty "big-name" applications that would simply choke with that <XML/> tag name. XML is actually "reserved", please take a look at [this section](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn) of the XML Spec. To quote: "*Names beginning with the string "xml", or with any string which would match (('X'|'x') ('M'|'m') ('L'|'l')), are reserved for standardization in this or future versions of this specification.*"

Always play nice with the specs....

Answer (score 1):

**Any global element you define in the schema is a potential root element in the the instance document.** If you doesn't want this behavior then make sure you have only one global element definition in the xsd. It has nothing to do with the tool (though xml editors can simplify this).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I was thinking maybe i just need to create another xsd with 1 element and ref all elements form first xsd in it. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @bunnyjesse112 moving elements to different xsd's doesn't solve the problem if they are still globally defined